# MongoWriteException when inserting into Mongodb with composite custom _id

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB remote server that I am using.

My KEY is a custom object that has other nested objects in it.

Simple inserting works fine, although if I try to run

```java
collection.replaceOne(eq("_id", KEY), document, new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
```

I get com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: .......

If I have only have primitives in the key it works fine. Of course the value of the KEY is not changed (traced all the way down).

Is this a Mongo Java Driver bug with the ReplaceOne function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out for Mongo filters, the order of json properties matter. With debugging it is possible to see what the actual orders of the properties in the filters are and then you can set your model properties order with @JsonPropertyOrder("att1", att2") so they match in order.

It was confirmed by a member of Mongo team.
Mongo ticket-> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3392